# Return a database row, based on a field laravel

Tags: laravel

I'am having problem trying to retrive just an element of a database:

The code response whit this line:

> "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent(): Argument #1
> ($content) must be of type ?string,
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder given, called in
> /home/julian/Documentos/Programacion/LARAVEL/portalCiudadanoBack/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php
> on line 72"

```
public function validate_new_city(Request $request)
{
    $validated = $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'confirmation_code' => 'required',
    ]);


    $city = City::where('name', $validated['name'] );

    return ($city);
}
```

Comment: Also add to last the query  `->get()`

Comment: you haven't executed the query you are just building a query at the moment and returning the builder, which is not the result of a query

Comment: You must add the method `->get()` if you want to get the collection. Otherwise use `->first()` to retrieve the first element from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Add the query with

```
->get()
```

or

```
->first()
```

or
you can check the argument with

```
dd(argument);
```

so you know the type of the argument if it not string